# How do I install mono 5.18.0?

Tags: software-installation, mono

I would like to install **[Mono 5.18.0](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.18.0/)** on Ubuntu 20.04. All I could find was an installation guide for [accessing older releases](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/#accessing-older-releases) which technically breaks down to:

> If you want to pin an older version of Mono you can modify the Debian repository to
> “stable-jessie/snapshots/X.XX.X” instead of “stable-jessie”. For
> example, “stable-jessie/snapshots/3.10.0” will lock you to that
> version.

How do I do that? My `/etc/apt/sources.list/d/mono-official-stable.list` file includes the following record, `deb https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu stable-focal main`. Will it work if I edit it like this?

```
deb https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu 5.18.0
```

and then

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mono-develo # or mono-complete?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the following syntax

```
deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu bionic/snapshots/5.18 main
```

In the above line *bionic* is used because it has [5.18 branch](https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu/dists/bionic/snapshots/).

But this will not work on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS because of outdated dependencies.
So you have to consider using Docker or VM with 18.04 LTS inside to proceed.